# Pickle error when trying to save a top2vec model with embeddings using mlflow

Tags: pickle, embedding, mlflow

Hello stackoverflow community,
I have a problem with saving a `top2vec` model with `universal sentence encoder` embedding using `mlflow`. It throws the following error.
`PickleError: can't pickle repeated message fields, convert to list first`

I use the following code to train the `top2vec` model and create and instantiate the `PythonModel` class required by `mlflow`.

```
model = Top2Vec(documents=doc_list, document_ids=ids_list, embedding_model='universal-sentence-encoder')

max_num_recomm = 50
class Top2VecModel(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._tm = model

    def d_by_d_search(self, id):
        results = self._tm.search_documents_by_documents(doc_ids=id, num_docs=max_num_recomm)
        return results

    def d_by_kw_search(self, kw):
        results = self._tm.search_documents_by_keywords(keywords=kw, num_docs=max_num_recomm)
        return results

ml_flow_model = Top2VecModel()
```

The code above code creates the following log.

```
2023-00-00 15:31:25,238 - top2vec - INFO - Pre-processing documents for training
INFO:top2vec:Pre-processing documents for training
c:\Code\.venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py:528: UserWarning: The parameter 'token_pattern' will not be used since 'tokenizer' is not None'
  warnings.warn(
2023-00-00 15:31:25,264 - top2vec - INFO - Downloading universal-sentence-encoder model
INFO:top2vec:Downloading universal-sentence-encoder model
2023-00-00 15:31:33,700 - top2vec - INFO - Creating joint document/word embedding
INFO:top2vec:Creating joint document/word embedding
2023-00-00 15:31:34,167 - top2vec - INFO - Creating lower dimension embedding of documents
INFO:top2vec:Creating lower dimension embedding of documents
2023-00-00 15:31:37,291 - top2vec - INFO - Finding dense areas of documents
INFO:top2vec:Finding dense areas of documents
2023-00-00 15:31:37,316 - top2vec - INFO - Finding topics
INFO:top2vec:Finding topics
```

The code works fine up to this point; however, when I try to save the model using `mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path='./model', python_model=ml_flow_model)`, I get the following error.

```
File c:\Code\.venv\lib\site-packages\mlflow\pyfunc\__init__.py:1332, in save_model(path, loader_module, data_path, code_path, conda_env, mlflow_model, python_model, artifacts, signature, input_example, pip_requirements, extra_pip_requirements, **kwargs)
   1321     return _save_model_with_loader_module_and_data_path(
   1322         path=path,
   1323         loader_module=loader_module,
   (...)
   1329         extra_pip_requirements=extra_pip_requirements,
   1330     )
   1331 elif second_argument_set_specified:
-> 1332     return mlflow.pyfunc.model._save_model_with_class_artifacts_params(
   1333         path=path,
   1334         python_model=python_model,
   1335         artifacts=artifacts,
   1336         conda_env=conda_env,
   1337         code_paths=code_path,
   1338         mlflow_model=mlflow_model,
   1339         pip_requirements=pip_requirements,
   1340         extra_pip_requirements=extra_pip_requirements,
   1341     )

File c:\Code\.venv\lib\site-packages\mlflow\pyfunc\model.py:164, in _save_model_with_class_artifacts_params(path, python_model, artifacts, conda_env, code_paths, mlflow_model, pip_requirements, extra_pip_requirements)
...
--> 632         return Pickler.dump(self, obj)
    633     except RuntimeError as e:
    634         if "recursion" in e.args[0]:

PickleError: can't pickle repeated message fields, convert to list first
```

I have tried to save the model along with the embedding as an artifact using `mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path='test', python_model=ml_flow_model, artifacts={"universal-sentence-encoder": model.embed()})` but I got this error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [69], line 8
      1 # mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path='test', python_model=ml_flow_model, artifacts={"universal-sentence-encoder": "https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4"})
      2 # mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(
      3 #     path='./test',
   (...)
      6 #     # artifacts={"universal-sentence-encoder": model.embed}
      7 #     )
----> 8 mlflow.pyfunc.save_model(path='test', python_model=ml_flow_model, artifacts={"universal-sentence-encoder": model.embed()})

File c:\Code\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\saved_model\load.py:704, in _call_attribute(instance, *args, **kwargs)
    703 def _call_attribute(instance, *args, **kwargs):
--> 704   return instance.__call__(*args, **kwargs)

File c:\Code\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py:153, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
    151 except Exception as e:
    152   filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
--> 153   raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
    154 finally:
    155   del filtered_tb

File c:\Code\.venv\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function_spec.py:509, in _convert_inputs_to_signature(inputs, input_signature, flat_input_signature)
    503   flatten_inputs = nest.flatten_up_to(
    504       input_signature,
...
ValueError: Structure of Python function inputs does not match input_signature:
  inputs: (
    )
  input_signature: (
    TensorSpec(shape=<unknown>, dtype=tf.string, name=None)).
```

I should add that if I train the model without using the universal sentence encoder embedding, it works fine. I am using `top2vec==1.0.28` and `mlflow==2.0.1`.
I have read many of the related `tensorflow` document as `Top2Vec` uses that; however, I have not been successful in finding the root cause of the error. I would appreciate your help with this.

Best Regards,
Javid